# Internet Explorer 9, 8 , 7 compatibility issue for Drupal site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal, cross-browser

Guyz currently I'm facing an IE compatibility issue on versions 9, 8 & 7. My site is on Drupal & its perfectly showing on Chrome, Firefox & IE 10. I have checked other IE version compatibility by pressing f12 on IE then I changed its versions. Currently site is align to center by using margin:auto; in css. When I change IE version from 10 to 9 site showing all its content to left align & it is the same result for IE 8 & IE 7.

I have used IE meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

but nothing happens. you can check my site: http://mtp.bcinewmedia.com/

Please provide fast solution. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmtp.bcinewmedia.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 shows your probable problem.

Comment: Do you have a valid doctype on your page?

Comment: Yes, Its has doctype:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are script and style-tags in front of your doctype, move the scripts and styles to your head or body and it should be allright.